# Comparing datasets for unique matches in Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Let’s say you have signals coming into Google Cloud Dataflow from two different pubsub topics, and you want to compare signals from one topic with signals from the other topic and generate a match if they’re equal. If there are multiple equal signals coming in on one of the topics simultaneously (or almost simultaneously), then we should not generate a match. Is it possible to generate matches in Dataflow in near real time in a way that lets us be 100% certain that the generated matches are correct (i.e. that there are no false positives)? If so, how would you implement it? Since data could arrive late into Dataflow’s time windows, I suspect this is quite difficult.

To simplify, if we get an “A” from one pubsub topic and an “A” from the other topic as well, we should generate a match, but only if there aren’t any other A’s coming in on either topic at about the same time (plus or minus 1 second, say).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, I would break it down as follows. I will use our standard four questions, since it is helpful in this case.

- "*What* are you computing?" - You are doing a stream join, and based on your description I think you will want to choose a [`CoGroupByKey`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/join/CoGroupByKey)-based join.
- "*Where* in event time do you want to group your data?" - You are interested in viewing events together if they occur nearby in event time. This corresponds roughly to the [`Sessions`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/windowing/Sessions) that are provided in the SDK. But I can't tell if you want the session to be over both of the streams, or each one individually. Hopefully my answer gives you enough to work from.
- "*When* do you want to produce output?" - Based on your goal of 100% certainty, I think you want to produce output only after you have decided to drop all further data. To actually have 100% certainty, you have to know something about where the data is coming from (this is independent of Dataflow).
- "*How* do refinements of prior outputs relate?" - Since you don't have multiple outputs for a single join result, this is a non-issue.

Let's suppose you have these inputs:

```java
PCollection<String> streamA
PCollection<String> streamB
```

if you want to do this matching + deduplication based on simultaneity across the streams, then you can simply window into `Sessions` and do a `CoGroupByKey`:

```java
PCollection<KV<String, String>> windowedA = streamA
    .apply(WithKeys.of(String v -> v))
    .apply(Window.into(
        Sessions.withGapDuration(Duration.standardSeconds(1))));

PCollection<KV<String, String>> windowedB = // ditto

// Set up join handles
TupleTag<String> tagA = new TupleTag<String>() {};
TupleTag<String> tagb = new TupleTag<String>() {};

KeyedPCollectionTuple joinInput =
    KeyedPCollectionTuple
        .of(tagA, windowedA)
        .and(tagB, windowedB);

PCollection<String> result = joinInput

    // Group streams together by shared key
    .apply(CoGroupByKey.create())

    // Eliminate all but 1-to-1 matches
    .apply(Filter.by(
        KV<String, CoGbkResult> joined ->
            Iterables.size(joined.getValue().getAll(tagA)) == 1
            && Iterables.size(joined.getValue().getAll(tagB)) == 1))

    // The key is all we care about
    .apply(Keys.create());
```

The collection `result` contains the strings with a near-simultaneous match but no duplicates within one second. Your real use case may require some tweaking.

If you want to separately deduplicate the two streams, that is slightly more complex, but not too much. You will need to separately session and `GroupByKey` for each stream, and then re-window according to how you want to window the join output.